# Order of ARRAY not maintained after converting XML to ARRAY in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

After using the simplexml_file_load in PHP I tried to use some code (XmlToArray()) I found in Php.NET(http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.simplexml.php) to convert the xml to an array so that I can process the response and then do a post it to a given URL.

However, the order that was defined in the XML doc is NOT how the array was displayed in my terminal when I did a print_r(array).

Is there a way to maintain the same order that is listed in the XML in the array?  Any help/direction would be appreciated.

Here is the xml as it is local to my machine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<order xmlns="http://www.shutterfly.com/orderv2/order">
    <version>2.0</version>
    <orderNo>sfly.000020513524-7001536_28935-tb.33</orderNo>
    <orderDate>2012-09-21 09:52:53 PDT</orderDate>
    <processing>
        <statusCallback>http://orderfulfillment.shutterfly.com/ogateway-test/status/sfly/xpressdocs/
        </statusCallback>
    </processing>
    <suborders>
        <suborder>
            <suborderNo>51917</suborderNo>
            <deliveryEstimate>
                <earliest>2012-10-01 00:00:00 PDT</earliest>
                <latest>2012-10-05 00:00:00 PDT</latest>
            </deliveryEstimate>
            <greeting>
                <line1>Ordered for you by Andrew Mullen on 09/21/12.</line1>
                <line2>Save 20% on Holiday Cards November 20 - 30 at Shutterfly
                </line2>
            </greeting>
            <shipAddr>
                <name>burkina faso</name>
                <address1>1234 burkina road</address1>
                <address2></address2>
                <city>yako</city>
                <region>R21</region>
                <postCode></postCode>
                <countryCode>BF</countryCode>
                <countryName>Burkina Faso</countryName>
            </shipAddr>
            <shipMethod>INTLSTD</shipMethod>
            <additionalFulfillers>false</additionalFulfillers>
            <items>
                <item>
                    <itemNo>36</itemNo>
                    <sku>6X8FLATCARD06</sku>
                    <description>6x8 Stationery Card - Stacy Claire Boyd</description>
                    <quantity>1</quantity>
                    <product>
                        <stationery>
                            <formFactor>6x8</formFactor>
                            <paperFinish>MATTE</paperFinish>
                            <orientation>LANDSCAPE</orientation>
                            <image>
                                <location>http://orderfulfillment.shutterfly.com/fulfillment-test/image/1200/000020513524-7001536_28935--164044--315625--canvas.jpg
                                </location>
                            </image>
                            <boc>
                                <location>http://orderfulfillment.shutterfly.com/fulfillment-test/image/1200/000020513524-7001536_28935--164044--315626--canvas.jpg
                                </location>
                            </boc>
                            <copyright>
                                <text>6X8FLATCARD06</text>
                            </copyright>
                        </stationery>
                    </product>
                    <envelopes>
                        <envelope>
                            <toAddress>
                                <font>
                                    <fontName>Arial</fontName>
                                    <fontSize>12</fontSize>
                                </font>
                                <name>FPO Tester</name>
                                <companyTitle></companyTitle>
                                <address1>PSC 812 Box 2640</address1>
                                <address2></address2>
                                <city>FPO</city>
                                <region>AE</region>
                                <postCode>09627</postCode>
                                <countryCode>USA</countryCode>
                                <countryName>United States of America</countryName>
                            </toAddress>
                            <fromAddress>
                                <font>
                                    <fontName>Arial</fontName>
                                    <fontSize>12</fontSize>
                                </font>
                                <name>Andrew Mullen</name>
                                <companyTitle></companyTitle>
                                <address1>2333 W. El Moro Circle</address1>
                                <address2></address2>
                                <city>Mesa</city>
                                <region>AZ</region>
                                <postCode>85202</postCode>
                                <countryCode>USA</countryCode>
                                <countryName>United States of America</countryName>
                            </fromAddress>
                        </envelope>
                    </envelopes>
                </item>
            </items>
        </suborder>
    </suborders>
</order>
```

Here is the XMLToArray() that I picked up from PHP.net:

```
function XMLToArray($xml)
{
    if ($xml instanceof SimpleXMLElement) {
        $children = $xml->children();
        $return = null;
    }

    foreach ($children as $element => $value) {
        if ($value instanceof SimpleXMLElement) {
            $values = (array) $value->children();

            if (count($values) > 0) {
                $return[$element] = XMLToArray($value);
            } else {
                if (!isset($return[$element])) {
                    $return[$element] = (string) $value;
                } else {
                    if (!is_array($return[$element])) {
                        $return[$element] = array($return[$element], (string) $value);
                    } else {
                        $return[$element][] = (string) $value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (is_array($return)) {
        return $return;
    } else {
        return $false;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.  Regards.

Comment: Leave the link of the xml file if it is on a live server, will be easy for us to see the xml order and then help you that way

Comment: Sorry about that I just put the XML on this post.  Thank you for your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

When I test the provided code I found that it worked fine with the snippet of xml that you provided but if added additional items for example it lost them in the array output.

Rather than debug the function,  can I suggest that you try this one, which seemed to work for me:

From Frederic 2008 @ [Source of code sample](http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=87283)

```
/**
 * Parse a SimpleXMLElement object recursively into an Array.
 * Attention: attributes skipped
 *
 *
 * @param $xml The SimpleXMLElement object
 * @param $arr Target array where the values will be stored
 * @return NULL
 */
private function convertXmlObjToArr( $obj, &$arr )
{
    $children = $obj->children();
    $executed = false;
    foreach ($children as $elementName => $node)
    {
        if( array_key_exists( $elementName , $arr ) )
        {
            if(array_key_exists( 0 ,$arr[$elementName] ) )
            {
                $i = count($arr[$elementName]);
                $this->convertXmlObjToArr ($node, $arr[$elementName][$i]);    
            }
            else
            {
                $tmp = $arr[$elementName];
                $arr[$elementName] = array();
                $arr[$elementName][0] = $tmp;
                $i = count($arr[$elementName]);
                $this->convertXmlObjToArr($node, $arr[$elementName][$i]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $arr[$elementName] = array();
            $this->convertXmlObjToArr($node, $arr[$elementName]);   
        }
        $executed = true;
    }
    if(!$executed&&$children->getName()=="")
    {
        $arr = (String)$obj;
    }

    return ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I appreciate the reply and the help.  Regards.